# Why does the command line hang if I mistype a command?

Tags: bash, anaconda, debian, conda, freeze

I connect via SSH to an external server running Debian v5.0.4. Since last week, if I mis-spell a command - for example, 'cd..' instead of 'cd ..', or 'exti' instead of 'exit' - the command line hangs. Nothing I've tried unhangs it. Instead, I have to close the terminal window and start again. Just before this started, I installed 'Anaconda2', so I wondered if this is somehow responsible as I know it can have unintended consequences. Please note that I did use this command when installing conda:

`conda config --set auto_activate_base false`

Here's what I've tried to fix it so far:

Whilst hanging:

- Ctrl+C
- Ctrl+K
- Ctrk+J
- Return
- Esc

Whilst not hanging:

- reset
- Deleted text block added to '.bashrc' by Conda
- Added 'set -x' to .bashrc file
- Copied .bashrc from /etc/skel/.bashrc to home directory to set to default
- conda clean --all
- rm ~/Applications/anaconda2/ (a number of .nfs files remained, saying 'device busy'
- Removed hidden files in ~/ created by conda (.condarc)

I'm fresh out of ideas and no other queries of this nature have remained unsolved after attempting at least one of the above. Can anyone help me fix this problem, please?

Comment: Isn't Debian one of the distros that try to be smart for you and suggest what you meant when you submit an incorrect command? That helper could very well be your culprit. I suspect this may be more of a Debian / generic computing question; forum with people better equipped to answer.

Comment: Maybe you've somehow broken `command_not_found_handle`? Run `declare -f command_not_found_handle` and see if there is anything that might cause an infinite loop or something. I disagree with the comment above though, as OP suspected, it is most probably conda's broken installation mechanism to blame

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestions. @oguzismail - I tried running 'declare' as suggested but got no output? Even 'man <command> just hangs. I have, however, just found that if I change the PATH as follows: `PATH=/bin:/sbin` then no basic commands are found but the hanging issue goes away. Making this change: `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` brings back the functionality and still removes the hang. But my PATH contains no mentions of conda or python. Can you tell what this might mean?

Comment: Looks like one of your directories in `PATH` is on an automounted file system that's not available. Try reducing your path with `PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH):/usr/local/bin` in your bash profile.

Comment: @Jens - that did the trick, thank you. I'm assuming this has essentially overwritten any existing additions to the PATH and put it back to the 'default settings' as it were?

Comment: Well, the system's default setting is what `getconf PATH` returns. Add to that only what you need. System administrators sometimes make the PATH contain everything under the sun, but that's bad.

Comment: Ahh, I see! Perfect, thank you so much!